# Any idea why a variable used in a FOR loop cannot be used in Array? JS + Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have a pretty simple issue I just cannot figure it out:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<button>SHOW X!</button>
<result></result>


n = 0; //x
i = 0;

$('button').live('click', function () {

    for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
     $('result').append((($('textarea').val().split("2011")[i]).split("]")[1].split(",")[n].split(" = ")[1]));

    }

});
```

For some reason when I use an integer in **("2011")[2]** instead of **"i"**, it works. Using "i", it fails to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/KRBxp/

Comment: How do you know that the array has `5` elements? What is the content of the textarea?

Comment: Anyway, I recommend using jQuery caching.

Comment: Basically you just have to break that massive long line with the splits on it into individual statements, then walk through them with a debugger figuring out which one is breaking. If you do that (divide and conquer), it's likely to be pretty obvious in the end.

Comment: I do not know that the array has 5 elements I just want the first 5

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I feel like that is a lot of work. The array has at least 5 elements that are split at "2011", I can see the first or second by just replacing i with 0 or 1

Comment: @Taylor: 2-5 minutes, tops, to break that line up into individual parts. Another 2 minutes to walk through it with a debugger. Trivial, and more to the point, it's bog standard programming technique: Walk the code.

Comment: @Taylor - follow TJ's advice. Also provide sample data and what you expect as a result, not just "it works with this but not with other things".

Answer (score 0):

T.J. you were right. It works now:

```
$('button').live('click', function () {

    $('#result').empty();

    var type = $(this).attr('data-type') ;

    var newvalues = $('textarea').val().split('2011');

    for(var i=1; i < newvalues.length; i++) {
        $('#result').append(newvalues[i].split("] ")[1].split(",")[type].split(" = ")[1]+'<br>');
    }
});
```